# How to create a unique hash for my class to use as a dictionary key

Tags: c#, hash

I am really confused how to use my class for a key in a dictionary.

I need to store key value pairs of my node class so i know what path i have traversed on my double connected graph.

So i need to create a unique hash for my class to use the node as a key. But i have no idea what i am meant to do to implement it.

My node class is a simple one:

```
  public class Node
  {
        public Vector2 Position;
        public List<Node> Connections;
  }
```

And in my graph traversal script I need to use a dictionary like this:

```
    //store paths "From"=> key, "To"=> value
    Dictionary<Node, Node> _visitedPaths;
```

On the Microsoft website it says:

> *Two objects that are equal return hash codes that are equal. However, the reverse is not true: **equal hash codes do not imply object
> equality, because different (unequal) objects can have identical hash
> codes.***

So if my understanding on this is correct, two different objects can create identical hash codes, so I need to implement my own hash code but I am not sure how I can guarantee to generate a unique hash code for each node object.

Comment: See especially https://stackoverflow.com/a/56539595/3538012

Comment: If you have more than 4,294,967,295 nodes then you can't provide a unique hash for each node. This is why the quoted statement is true. You need to check equality in addition to matching hash codes.